# I'm getting a 404 when trying to set the flair on a post with the Reddit API and RedditSharp wrapper

Tags: c#, reddit

A bot I created submitted [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/GamingNewsTest/comments/4e43u4/highlight_fallens_lastsecond_plant_and_1v1_clutch/) post to [/r/GamingNewsTest](https://www.reddit.com/r/GamingNewsTest). I'm using the [RedditSharp](https://github.com/SirCmpwn/RedditSharp) wrapper and when I try to call `SetFlair', a 404 exception occurs.

Here's the code I'm currently testing:

```
subreddit.SubmitPost(redditPost.Title, redditPost.URL, "", "", true).SetFlair("Hearthstone", "");
```

I checked the parameters the wrapper is sending to the [reddit API](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#POST_api_flair):

- api_type : `json`
- css_class :
- link : `t3_4e44j3`
- name: `GamingNewsBot`
- text: `Hearthstone`
- uh / X-Modhash header : No idea. The wrapper handles this internally. Not sure how to grab it without stepping into the assembly.

I'm passing nothing to `css_class` because there's no associated class at the moment. I can set it manually without one. Do I need to pass something to it? Any other ideas why this might be occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is bug in RedditSharp. When you do this:

```
var post = subreddit.SubmitPost(title, url, "", "", true);
```

returned post has `SubredditName` property set to null. When you then do

```
post.SetFlair("Hearthstone", "");
```

It posts correct data but to wrong url: because SubredditName is null, it posts data to `/r//api/flair`, hence 404 error.

Temporary fix would be to set this property before setting flair:

```
post.SubredditName = subreddit.Name;
post.SetFlair("Hearthstone", "");
```

In long term you have to contact with developer of this library and ask him to fix this bug.